# Power BI Desktop : Draw dynamic vertical lines in line chart graph while selecting multiple values in my slicer

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, linechart

I have a table that contains the folowing data :

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G2lH.png)

I want to create a line chart using :
- X axix : column **Milestone**
- Y axis : Total Yes/No (measure = Cumulative sum of column 'Yes/No')
- legend : column **SerialNumber**

I also have a slicer based on the column **SerialNumber**.

I want that my graph shows a vertical line for each milestone (M1, M2) for each SerialNumber.

I can't find a solution to create those vetical lines except using the "X Axis Constant Line" in the analytics pane. It works well if I select one SerialNumber, but if I want to visualise 2 or plus SerialNumbers at the same time this solution doesn't work.

That's what I get if I select multiple values in my slicer :
[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq9mf.png)

But what I want is actually this (vertical lines for each value selected in the slicer) :
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhJhd.png)

I hope there is a way to make this.

Thank you !